# js (nodeJS) parsing JSON based object (string as identifier)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, string, object

I've the following object containing json data.

```
{
    "item1": {
        "2017-07-17": {"price": 67},
        "2016-07-16": {"price": 453},
        "2016-07-15": {"price": 435},
        ...
    },
    "item2": {
        "2017-07-17": {"price": 642},
        "2016-07-16": {"price": 643},
        "2016-07-15": {"price": 593},
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

To parse this code I use:

```
highest_price = Infinity;
for (var item in prices) {

  if(keys.includes(item)){

    console.log(item + " found");

  }
}
```

How can I get now the "highest" price only for "today"? The if statement makes sure I only get "relevant" items, but how can I access the "current" price and make sure in the end I get the highest price for all items I filter through.
My main problem is how to "get only" the current date property?

I loop each item, after this I check if the item name is in an array. For every item which is in this array `if(keys.includes(item))` I would like to get the "actual" price and then get the highest price for all of the items inside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code you can find the item maximum and current price. I think this code can be optimized even better since I am looping twice.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/3afz92yr/2/

```
var prices = {
    "item1": {
        "2017-07-17": {"price": 800},
        "2016-07-16": {"price": 453},
        "2017-07-19": {"price": 10},
        "2016-07-15": {"price": 435}
    },
    "item2": {
        "2017-07-17": {"price": 622},
        "2016-07-16": {"price": 643},
        "2016-07-15": {"price": 593}

    }
};
var items = Object.keys(prices);
var dateprices = {};
items.forEach(function(item){
  if(keys.includes(item)){
      for(var k in prices[item]){
        dateprices[k] = dateprices.hasOwnProperty(k)?dateprices[k]:[];
        dateprices[k].push(prices[item][k].price);        
      }    
  }
})

Object.entries(dateprices).forEach(function([key, value]){
    console.log(key);
  dateprices[key].sort(function(a,b){
     return b - a;
  });   
})
alert("Highest price on 2017-07-17 is "+dateprices["2017-07-17"][0])
```

Comment: i only need the highest price from "actual" date, for the example above this would mean output like `highest price: 642`. Hope you understand?

Comment: what actual date means? so don't you need price item wise?\

Comment: I only need to get the "highest" price  (only the highest one) from ALL items I filtered using the if condition for the actual date. For the exmaple code above this would be 642. Only note the latest price.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how to include my check `if(keys.includes(item))`, so only defined objects are included?